# Put element ABOVE another element

Tags: css

we have this weird situation where we have the following DOM:

```
<div class="container1"> ... </div>
<div class="container2"> ... </div>
```

We now want that container2 appears ABOVE container1. 
Normally, both containers are wrapper beside each other, `container1` is the main content and `container2` is the sidebar.

The Sidebar has to be OVER the main content. Both elements have an unknown height.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are they both the same width?

Comment: Yes, width on both is 100%.

Comment: When you say above do you mean overlaid or just coming first on the page...it's not clear.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with display: flex and order.

```css
main{
   display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


div{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.first{
   background: blue;
  order: 2;
}

.second{
  background: red;
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Looks like thats it - will try and give you a feedback ASAP.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much. - how browser compatible is this solution? Isn't flex css3 only? Would that mean that older IE versions cannot show this correctly?

Comment: Thank you very much for that Info!

Comment: I've just found this: http://tanalin.com/en/projects/css-global-order/ that seems to work with IE 7+. Just in case you needed old IE support ;)

Answer (score -2):

Use `position: absolute` on both divs they'll stack up